# Changing Column Alignment to "RIGHT" in iTextSharp from Win Form

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to align one of my datagrid column of "Amount" to right side but unable to do so while trying to create PDF using itextsharp. All the columns are left aligned, some colums should be left aligned and the last column should be right aligned. Please help

Below listed is the code.

```
PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.ColumnCount);
            pdfTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 5f, 10f, 10f, 7f, 9f });
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
            pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 90;
            pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {

                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText,     fontTitle2));
                cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
            }

 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {

                    pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(),   fontTitle));

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is strange, because you create your first row in a way that leads to assume that you already know the answer to your question.

When you create your first row, you do:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText, fontTitle2));
cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
```

You create a `PdfPCell` in *text mode* and you set the alignment to `ALIGN_CENTER` at the level of the cell. This is correct.

When you create the subsequent rows, you do:

```
pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), fontTitle));
```

This also creates a `PdfPCell` in *text mode* (internally) and the alignment of the *default cell* is used. If you didn't change this alignment, the alignment is `ALIGN_LEFT`.

Instead of using:

```
pdfTable.AddCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), fontTitle));
```

Why don't you use the knowledge you already had when you created the code for the first row?

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), fontTitle));
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
```

Of course: if some cells need `Element.ALIGN_LEFT` and other cells need `Element.ALIGN_RIGHT`, you'll have to add an if in your loop. That if should check if `cell` is the last cell in the `row` or not.

Comment: That solved the problem, however could you help with the if loop code please